# SVG stroke dash array CSS animation reverses course?

Tags: css, svg, jquery-animate

I have a simple path, to which i'm applying a dash array and a dash offset with CSS. Then I'm animating this simple construct. The animation changes the dash array and offset to decrease and then increase size again.

The odd thing is, the movement appears to reverse halfway through. Can anyone help with this? I'm sure it's not actually reversing, but that the math is causing an unexpected visual effect.

```css
.path {
  stroke-dasharray: 10;
  stroke-dashoffset: 10 30;
  animation: dash 5s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes dash {
   50%{
    stroke-dashoffset: 35%;
    stroke-dasharray: 0 87.5%;
  }
}
```

```html
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
  width="340px" height="333px" viewBox="0 0 340 333" enable-background="new 0 0 340 333" xml:space="preserve">

  <path class="path" fill="#FFFFFF" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="4" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M66.039,133.545c0,0-21-57,18-67s49-4,65,8
 s30,41,53,27s66,4,58,32s-5,44,18,57s22,46,0,45s-54-40-68-16s-40,88-83,48s11-61-11-80s-79-7-70-41
 C46.039,146.545,53.039,128.545,66.039,133.545z"/>
  
</svg>
```

For props the above is a very boiled down version of [this beautiful work](https://codepen.io/yoksel/pen/XJbzrO).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

per [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@keyframes)

> If a keyframe rule doesn't specify the start or end states of the animation (that is, 0%/from and 100%/to), browsers will use the element's existing styles for the start/end states. This can be used to animate an element from its initial state and back.

You've got one keyframe at 50% so animation goes to that at half-time and then back to the initial state at full time.

Comment: [palm and face meet in a thunderous clap]. That’s embarrassing really, I should have known that. Thank you!